# How to obtain on click event the object's details from a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Hi all i'm new on stackoverflow, and also about android development..

Here's my problem guys: I've a result from a jsoncall, it's an array with inside a series of objects, all with their properties. I want a listview to appear in my activity containing -object.name-s. When i click on a listitem, the -object.id- of the selected item(rather of the object in it, not position, but the object-id that's stored in mysql and i have with jsoncall) is sent with an intent to another activity, that then will show all the object details. It can also send the whole object, in this way i do not have to recall json in the second activity to have details (maybe).

This is what i want. I tried to do all without a custom class, failing. So i did also some tests using a class called Event.
this is:
    ArrayList  event_name=new ArrayList();

```
try{

jArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json_data=null;
Event event;

for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    event = new Event (json_data.getInt("IDEvent"), json_data.getString("NameEvent"));      

    event_name.add(event.getName());

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.textViewList, event_name);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id){  ....problem is here.... }
            }//end for loop
```

With this solution the listview is working and it shows correctly objects names. But i cannot find a way to do onClick event..

```
Event eventOut = (Event) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

with this and then getID the app go in crash, also if i try to pass the whole object.
getName() and getID() are implemented in the Event class.

```
        private int getID(){    return IDEvent; }
    private String getName(){   return NameEvent;   }
```

please if someone can help me i appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position, long id){  
Event eventOut =event_name.getItem(position);
}
            }//
```

Comment: this wont work, because i used this:`event_name.add(event.getName());` in the for loop, so id is not in event_name.

Comment: SOLVED:
i added 
`final ArrayList <String> event_id=new ArrayList<String>();`
and
`event_id.add(json_data.getString("IDEvento"));`
to take track of id and finally used in the OnClick event
`NewIntent.putExtra("event_id", event_id.get(position));`
hope it will help to someone!